# Pom Dependency in a JSF project with Richfaces and MyFaces

Tags: jsf, maven, richfaces, pom.xml, myfaces

I want to build a JSF project with MAVEN. I tried to add the all dependencies i needed. Each time I get the errors.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

What should I add to this POM so that my project works as a real JSF project?

P.S I added the right richfaces dependencies. I got deploy problems on websphere like.

```
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1651)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$ApplicationMap.entrySet(ConfigureListener.java:1948)
```

Comment: I'm no Maven guy, so I won't go in detail, but I can at least tell that Websphere itself **already** ships with JSF libraries. You should be configuring it over there or at least turn it off if you want to control it from your web application on. The stacktrace contains lines of Mojarra (`com.sun.faces.*`) and thus indicates that it's **still** been used by Websphere.

Comment: @BalusC Is it possible do disable the websphere own libraries? I don't think that the libraries at wesphere all uptodate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Richfaces dependency you are using is just a `bom` - it lists a set of compatible "real" dependencies and should be used in the `dependencyManagement` section of your `pom`:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In the dependencies, you should have the implementation, like this:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
    <!--version>4.2.2.Final</version-->
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
    <!--version>4.2.2.Final</version-->
  </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

The version element of the dependencies is redundant, if you are using the `bom`. You are better off removing it, as you may unwillingly overrride the `bom` setting.

**EDIT:** the error you are getting looks like a configuration issue to me. Not sure what may have caused it. My advice is to start with a working webapp example and then add additional dependendcies. My favorite way is to let maven geneare a webapp from archetype:

`mvn archetype:generate`

you will then see a long list of possibl archetypes. Try something with a JSF in it, like `jsf-weld-servlet-webapp` or `weld-jsf-jee` or `richfaces-archetype-simpleapp`. These are known to work, and you can sample the `pom` and the rest of the project to see what may be missing.